# Correct 1921 Router to 2960 Switch Configuration for an External Connection

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst

Sorry for the newb question, I am trying to figure out how to best link up an subinterface on a Cisco 1921 router, with an external network, by connecting the router and the cable from the external network, to a Cisco Catalyst 2960 switch and isolating them into their own VLAN.
The external network recommended I use a 172.A.A.102 255.255.252 for my router IP, and ping 172.A.A.101 on their network. 
I was able to ping successfully by connecting the external network's cable to my laptop and configuring their IP information, but I cant ping from my router after what I setup:

1. I created the subinterface for the external network on my router with:

   `interface GigabitEthernet0/0.3
   encapsulation dot1Q 802
   ip address 172.A.A.102 255.255.255.252`
2. On the switch I configured two ports: f0/5 for the router, and f0/6 for the external network cable with:

`!

interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport mode trunk
 spanning-tree portfast
!

interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 802
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree portfast`

But unfortunately I cannot ping 172.A.A.101. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the VLAN 802 up? What is the result of a "show vlan" on the switch? Is the interface GigabitEthernet0/0.3 on the router up?

Comment: Yes VLAN 802 is up, `show vlan` presents `802  VLAN_NAME                    active    Fa0/6`, interface is up on the router: `GigabitEthernet0/0.3       172.A.A.102   YES manual up                    up`

Comment: Wow. Seems to have worked, I can ping the external network IP from the router now. `main1#ping 172.31.63.101
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 172.A.A.101, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/4 ms
`
 But from the catalyst switch, I can't ping 172.A.A.101 or 172.A.A.102, is this normal?

Comment: The switch doesn't have an IP in this network, and it can't since it's a /30 network which allow only 2 IPs - a waste, since the provider could use a /31 for the same result.  So yes , it is normal. Glad you found out. You could post what you did as an answer and accept it so the question doesn't pop up for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I did the right thing, I suppose I wasn't patient enough for the switch to start accepting packets.
Everything works as expected.

Comment: you should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.